# DataGridViewRow setting display

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a table with a status of 0,1,2 or 3. 
I have a datagridview with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I would like to have this have the values
Zero, One, Two, Three respectively.
I have an autou-generated datatable that fills the grid.
No matter what I do, the cell just shows the number that is stored in the database. 
how do i get a databound comboboxcell to display the value that i want ("one" instead of "1")
i also want the displayed values to be available, so the user can change from "one" to "two" and have 2 be sent to the database.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataTable with Status Code and Caption:

```
DataTable statusTable = new DataTable() ;
statusTable.AddColumn("Code"   ,system.typeof(Int32)) ;
statusTable.AddColumn("Caption",system.typeof(String));
for (int i=0;i<3;i++) 
{
  DataRow row = statusTable.newRow() ;
  row[0]=i ;
  row[1]=new string[] { "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three" }[i] ;
  statusTable.AddRow(row) ;
}
```

Bind the status DataTable to the Combobox column:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cb = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)DataGridView.Columns["StatusColumnName"] ; 
cb.DataSource    = statusTable ;
cb.ValueMember   = "Code" ;
cb.DisplayMember = "Caption;
```

*An alternartive to status DataTable is a List < Status >, where Status is a class with 2 public properties "Code" and "Caption".*